# Programa para imprimir diferencia máxima entre máximo y mínimo de vectores de una matriz da siempre '0'

Tags: c++

Resulta que quiero hacer un programa que tenga una función a la que se le pase una matriz y que para cada vector pase por referencia el máximo y el mínimo. En el main uso esos datos para calcular la diferencia ya que el propósito del programa es imprimir la diferencia máxima y la posición del vector (empezando por 1) dónde se encuentra dentro de la matriz.

Entrada:

```
2 2
3 9
9 3

1 5
-1 -1 -7 -1 0

2 1
1
8

2 4
9 9 9 9
2 9 9 2
```

Salida esperada:

```
la diferencia maxima es 7
la primera matriz con esta diferencia es la 2
```

Salida:

```
la diferencia maxima es 0
la primera matriz con esta diferencia es la 0
```

Adjunto el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<vector<int> > Matriu;

//Pre: mat no es vacía
//Post: ...
void min_max(const Matriu& mat, int& minim, int& maxim) {
    maxim = mat[0][0];
    minim = mat[0][0];
    int r = mat.size();
    int c = mat[0].size();
    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
            if (mat[i][j] > maxim) maxim = mat[i][j];
            else if (mat[i][j] < minim) minim = mat[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int r, c, maxim, minim, diferencia, countmat, diffcount;
    diferencia = countmat = diffcount = 0;
    while (cin >> r and cin >> c) {
        Matriu mat(r, vector<int>(c));
        for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
                cin >> mat[i][j];
            }
        }
        ++countmat;
        min_max(mat, maxim, minim);
        if (maxim - minim > diferencia) {
            diferencia = maxim - minim;
            diffcount = countmat;
        }
    }
    cout << "la diferencia maxima es " << diferencia << endl;
    cout << "la primera matriz con esta diferencia es la " << diffcount << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los parámetros están invertidos:

```
// Función 
void min_max(const Matriu& mat, int& minim, int& maxim);

// Llamada en main
min_max(mat, maxim, minim);
```

Solo tienes que pasarlos en el orden correcto:

```
min_max(mat, minim, maxim);
```

La explicación a por qué 0 sigue siendo la mayor diferencia es que al invertir los parámetros, la diferencia cambia de signo (negativo).

Entonces, 0 siempre será mayor que un número negativo:

```
if (maxim - minim > diferencia){
    ...
}
```

---

Para que funcione indistintamente deberías comparar distancias (con valor absoluto) ya que no existen las distancias negativas.

Bien podrías hacerlo de esta manera:

```
int distancia = maxim - minim;
if (distancia < 0)
    distancia = -distancia;

if (distancia > distanciaMayor){
    distanciaMayor = distancia;
    diffcount = countmat;
}
```

O comparando ambos casos:

```
int diferencia = maximo - minim;
if (diferencia > diferenciaMayor) {
    diferenciaMayor = diferencia;
    diffcount = countmat;
}
else if (-diferencia > diferenciaMayor) {
    diferenciaMayor = -diferencia;
    diffcount = countmat;
}
```